# Solaris similar command to Linux "tcpserver"

Tags: tcp, solaris, tcpserver

I'm looking for a command in Solaris OS that is similar to the Linux tcpserver command to send and receive messages over TCP :

example:
tcpserver localhost 3333 expect -c 'expect "hello" ; send "OK" ; expect "bye" ; send "see you\n"'

Thanks

Comment: I have found Netcat and I'm downloading it now ,,,I think it would be the solution for this

Answer (score 0):

You can download the package containing tcpserver and build it - follow the steps at http://cr.yp.to/ucspi-tcp/install.html.